# BizForm Email Notification

Tags: kentico

I'm using Kentico 8.1 and for some reason when I add a form record using BizFormItem.Insert() no email notifcation is generated.

I know the configuration is correct because when I add a record to the same form using the standard form and check the "Send notification e-mail" checkbox I see a generated email.

Is there a way to ensure that I get the same result when using BizFormItem.Insert() ?

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. I would like to use the "Send form data to e-mail" checkbox on the Form "Email Notification tab" to control the sending of the notification email but I don't seem to be able to find it in the BizFormInfo class. Am I able to access this value via the API ?

Comment: It's OK I realised I can use the FormSendToEmail property which is empty if notifications are unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any email behavior in the BizFormItem class, but you could use the classes in Kentico's CMS.EmailEngine namespace to create an email message and populate it with the data from your BizForm.

Take a look at [this article on Kentico's Email API](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/sending-e-mails-using-api) to see how to create emails in Kentico, then take a look at the code in step 3 of [this article on Kentico's BizForm API](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-display-data-of-bizform-for-print) to see how to get data from a BizForm.

Comment: Correct, e-mail functionality is built into a much higher layer. It's not BizForm's responsibility to send e-mails. You have to build it yourself if you want to create bizforms programmatically.